# Basic OpenGL Renderer

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently added this `ShaderBatch` to my engine, which takes care of rendering objects which share the same render technique (shader), like billboards and lights. I would like you to point out if there are any relevant changes I could make to my class.

PS: Is the term "ShaderBatch" appropriate ?

**ShaderBatch.h:**

```
/*
 * ShaderTechnique.h
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 9, 2015
 *      Author: mattmatt
 */

#pragma once

#include "alpha/Shader.h"
#include "alpha/Light.h"
#include "alpha/Camera.h"
#include "alpha/Transform.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

class ShaderBatch {
public:
    ShaderBatch();
    virtual ~ShaderBatch(){}

    void SetMatrices(const Camera& camera, const Transform& transform);

    void Begin();
    void End();
protected:
    Shader m_shader;
    Camera m_camera;
    Transform m_transform;
};

class LightBatch : public ShaderBatch{
public:
    LightBatch();
    virtual ~LightBatch(){}

    void SetMaterial(Material material){
        m_material = material;
    }
    void SetPointLight(PhongLight light){
        m_light = light;
    }
    void SetCameraPosition(glm::vec3 pos){
        m_camPosition = pos;
    }

    void Begin();
    void End();

private:
    Material m_material;
    PhongLight m_light;
    glm::vec3 m_camPosition;
};
```

**ShaderBatch.cpp:**

```
#include "ShaderBatch.h"

ShaderBatch::ShaderBatch(){}

void ShaderBatch::SetMatrices(const Camera& camera, const Transform& transform){
    m_camera = camera;
    m_transform = transform;
}

void ShaderBatch::Begin(){
     m_shader->Bind();
         m_camera.SetUniforms(m_shader, m_transform);
}

void ShaderBatch::End(){}

LightBatch::LightBatch()
    : ShaderBatch(),
      m_material(CreateTexture("res/images/Debug.png")),
      m_light(PhongLight()),
      m_camPosition(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
{
    ShaderBatch::m_shader = CreateShader("res/shaders/basicShader.glslv", "res/shaders/phongShader.glslf");
}

void LightBatch::Begin(){
    ShaderBatch::Begin();
        m_material.Bind(ShaderBatch::m_shader);
            m_material.SetUniforms(ShaderBatch::m_shader);
            m_light.SetUniforms(m_shader);
}

void LightBatch::End(){}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "alpha.h"

#include <btBulletCollisionCommon.h>
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>

#include "ShaderBatch.h"

static const unsigned WIDTH = 1000.0;
static const unsigned HEIGHT = 900.0;

int main(int argc, char **args){

    Window window(200, 10, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Alpha engine - release alpha 0.0", true, false);
    window.SetMouseVisible(false);

    Mesh box1 = CreateMesh("res/models/Terrain.obj");

    Shader shader = CreateShader("res/shaders/basicShader.glslv", "res/shaders/phongShader.glslf");

    LightBatch batch;

    Camera camera(glm::vec3(0, 5.0, 2.5), 70.0f, (float)window.GetWidth() / (float)window.GetHeight(), 0.01, 1000.0f);
    Transform transform;
    InputHandler input = InputHandler();
    PhongLight phongLight;
    phongLight.SetPosition(glm::vec3(-1.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f));
    phongLight.SetIntensity(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
    phongLight.SetAttenuation(0.01);

    Material material(CreateTexture("res/images/Terrain.jpg"), CreateTexture("res/images/TerrainNormalMap.jpg"));

    bool isRunning = true;
    unsigned FPS = 0;

    transform.GetPos() -= glm::vec3(.0, 8.5, .0);
    transform.GetScale() *= 7;

    util::InMainLoop(2000, isRunning,
    [&](float delta){
        window.Update();
        input.Update();
        isRunning = !(input.CloseRequested() || input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE));


        if(!input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_TAB)){
            util::ApplyFreeFPSLook(camera, input, window, delta, 0.01, 5.0, glm::ivec2(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2));
            window.SetMouseVisible(false);
        }
        else
            window.SetMouseVisible(true);


        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT))
            phongLight.SetPosition(phongLight.GetPosition() += glm::vec3(0.01, 0.0, 0.0));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT))
            phongLight.SetPosition(phongLight.GetPosition() -= glm::vec3(0.01, 0.0, 0.0));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_UP))
                    phongLight.SetPosition(phongLight.GetPosition() += glm::vec3(0.0, 0.01, 0.0));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN))
            phongLight.SetPosition(phongLight.GetPosition() -= glm::vec3(0.0, 0.01, 0.0));


        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_N))
            material = Material(CreateTexture("res/images/Terrain.jpg"),CreateTexture("res/images/TerrainNormalMap.jpg"));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_P))
            material = Material(CreateTexture("res/images/Terrain.jpg") ,CreateTexture("res/images/DefaultNormalMap.jpg"));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_F))
            material = Material(CreateTexture("res/images/Checkered.png") ,CreateTexture("res/images/TerrainNormalMap.jpg"));
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_TAB) && input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_L))
            glDrawMode(GL_LINES);
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_TAB) && input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_S))
                glDrawMode(GL_TRIANGLES);
        if(input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_TAB) && input.KeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_P))
                glDrawMode(GL_POINTS);

    },
    [&](){
            window.Clear(.0f, .0f, .0f, .0f);
            /*
            shader->Bind();
            camera.SetUniforms(shader, transform);
            material.SetUniforms(shader);
            phongLight.SetUniforms(shader);

            material.Bind(shader);
*/
            batch.SetMatrices(camera, transform);
            batch.SetMaterial(material);
            batch.SetPointLight(phongLight);
            batch.Begin();

            box1->Draw();

            window.SwapBuffers();
    },
    FPS
    );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;///YEHE ! EVERYTHING WENT RIGHT !

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Polling versus events**

In the update function you're *polling* the state. This means that every single frame, you're requesting state. In this case, it's about a few keys but if you have support for multiple players and controllers, this method is going to get computationally expensive. Responding on events is a little more complex, but worth considering for larger projects. Have a look at [events in sdl](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event). The same happens in the render function, where you set the material every single frame. Why not set the material when the material changes, so in the update? It is weird that a render function changes materials!

**Structure**

It may be that copy/pasting your code may have changed it a little, but at certain places you have more spaces than others, sometimes the `{` is on a newline, sometimes it is on the same, the destructor is in the headers while the constructor is not, ...

**C versus C++**

The style of `CreateShader` that returns a shader struct is a C-style construct. The C++ way of doing the same would be to give the Shader class a constructor that does the same as `CreateShader`.

**Const references & move operators**

If you pass a parameter by value it is copied over. So that means that every time someone calls `SetMaterial`, a copy of a Material object is created. The same for parameters in setters and constructors. To prevent useless copying, use [const references or move operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270408/3510322) where possible.

**Remove dead/useless code**

There is an end function, but it is never called nor implemented. So just remove it, and perhaps rename `begin`. (There is no use in creating functions because you think it *may* be useful in the future).

**Virtual/Override**

Mark functions you are going to overload as such. Mark the function in the base class `virtual` and add the `override` keyword in the derived class. This will help the compiler catch errors.

```
virtual void ShaderBatch::Begin();
virtual void LightBatch::Begin() override;
```

**ShaderBatch**

The naming seems to suggest a collection of meshes to be rendered with the same shader. Currently it is used to store the settings. For me personally, it would sound more logical if there is a list of items to render in that batch, and a call to a `render` function does all logic required to set-up and render all registered items. (e.g. store `box1` (that's a bit of an odd name for a terrain, isn't it?) inside of a list inside of the `ShaderBatch`)

Comment: 1°CreateShader() is actually more complex than you might think : actually, 80% of "classes" are in fact hidden smart pointers(shared_ptr) : the  Shader class, for instance is defined as : typdef Shader shared_ptr<CShader>; CreateShader actually returns a new shared_ptr : there is **no other way around !** All objects (like CShader) have their assignement operators disabled because of the fact that opengl is big state machine which was written in C (except for opengl 4.5+).

Comment: 2° Ok, I'll remove End(); will replace it with Execute(std::function<void>)...

Comment: 3° Sorry for the odd name :°) was playing with blender terrain, and did not change the actual name of the var., just the file value... And for the render by list, how would you do it exactly ? I give the ShaderBatch an std::vector at render, and render all primitives by getting their transform components ? But what if there are Lights involved ? Should I then pass those by Get/Sets to member vars ?

Comment: Is it ok like his ?

Comment: 1) Even if CreateShader returns a shared pointer, why not put it in a resourceManager class that manages all shaders, so that the same shader doesn't get instantiated twice?

Comment: 3) Yes - store lists of objects to render. These lists are usually the result of culling and they are stored depending on use case. For example, it can be a list of all objects to render with this shader if you want to minimize the number of shader changes. It can also be a list sorted on distance of the objects on the camera if you want to minimize overdraw. It can be a list of "special" primitives such as "DecalBatch". A list per light is possible, but probably not what you want if you have a deferred renderer.

Comment: Just one more thing... Isn't what mentioned about SDL(1) ? I'm using SDL2... Are things still the same ?   In SDL2, I use SDL event; SDL_PollEvent(e) to detect input...

Comment: @MattMatt Correct, my URL was a bit outdated and about SDL1 instead of SDL2, but the SDL_PollEvent has stayed (more or less) the same. I've updated the URL! :)

Comment: Thanks :) Just another thing : recently, I looked at the jmonkey engine api : It actually uses a thing called RootNode which acts like a sene; I could attach Entities, Light, or other things and they would render ! Do you think that's a good idea ?

Comment: How to represent and render a scene goes a bit out of the scope of a code review and a comment. There are many ways to do this that all have their pro's and cons, so I suggest you do some research or post this question over at [the gamedev stackexchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)